# Face Detector не срабатывает через некоторое время

Tags: android, kotlin

Всем привет,

Есть в fragment'е метод который получает много фотографии и находит на них лицо, дальше изменяет размер фото. Если открыть этот фрагмент 1-ый раз - то всё ок, если нажать back и опять открыть (так несколько раз) то фотки грузятся с сервера но `faces[i] == null`. В чем может быть проблема? Куда покопать. Использую `Google FaceApi`. При этом все проверки на ошибки проходит

```
fun loadImages(persons: List<Person>) {
    var result = ArrayList<Bitmap>()

    var detector = FaceDetector.Builder(activity.applicationContext)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
            .setTrackingEnabled(false)
            .build()

    for (person in persons) {
        if (person.image != null) {
            val bitmap = ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync(IMAGE_HOST + person.image) ?: continue
            if (!detector.isOperational) Log.e("Detector", "Error")

            var frame = Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build() ?: continue
            var faces = detector.detect(frame) ?: continue

            if (faces.size() > 0) {
                for (i in 0..faces.size()) {
                    if (faces[i] != null) {
                        var x = faces[i].position.x.toInt()
                        var y = faces[i].position.y.toInt()
                        var w = faces[i].width.toInt()
                        var h = faces[i].height.toInt()
                        var radius = h / 2

                        if (y < 0)
                            y = 0
                        result.add(getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, x +  w/ 2, y + h/ 2, radius))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (result.size > 0)
        showActor = true
    personAdapter.personal = result
    notifyChange()
    detector.release()
    Log.d("Detected", "TempSize" + result.size)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже что у вас там просто очередь на загрузку стоит.
Старый фрагмент уже "протух", но все что-то грузит.

Придумайте механизм прерывания цикла `for (person in persons)` если жизненный цикл фрагмента уже закончился.